# MySQL Workbench user input

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

My Question is how to get @userinput to work with mySQL.

Here is an example

```
SELECT *
FROM film
WHERE titel = @userinput;
```

but this query wont work with SQL workbench
If someone could help me with this that would be amezing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, since you come from MS Access environment your perception of Database might be different. In Ms Access, you have inbuilt database and variety of other features in the form of front-end.

MySQL is pure database where you work with SQL language which is pure text. With MySQL workbench you can create and mange MySQL schemas/tables/diagrams but it does not give you a front-end like MS Access does.

to have a user form you need to develop your own application, either in MS ACCESS or any other application which can connect to MySQL server and work with the tables.

Other than that: if you would like to work with parameters in MySQL, either you need to create stored procedures which take parameters, or set the parameters like

something like this;

```
SET @mTest := 'This is a test';
Select tbl_test where testField like @mTest;
```

hope you understand the different between MS Access and a database server.